# Class Not Found HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, spring, maven, zk

I have an existing spring maven project. My goal is to integrate ZK into my project so I just copied all libraries needed and made sure that they are properly configured in my Java build path. However, I kept on receiving the following error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class
org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener  
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)  
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)    
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)     
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's what I have added in my web.xml

```xml
  <listener>
        <description>
        Used to cleanup when a session is destroyed</description>
        <display-name>ZK Session cleaner</display-name>
        <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
            <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here's some part of my applicationContext.xml :

```xml
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.zkoss.spring.web.servlet.view.ZkResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".zul" />
    </bean>
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011726/java-lang-classnotfoundexception. In your case it would be zk.jar

Comment: I have zk.jar and it's already configured in my Build Path before I posted this question. Am I missing something?

Comment: It sounds like the jar containing the missing class is not being built into the war file. Please post your pom.xml file. Have you set compile scope for that jar in pom.xml?

Comment: @KissaSy, open your war/ear with winrar/winzip/... and search for zk.jar in your dependencies. If it's not there => pom configuration fault. If it's there see what version it is and if that version contains the class at the right place.